# Regular Expression for Validating & Tokenizing String

Tags: regex, validation, tokenize

I am trying to develop a regular expression for a special case:

It should accept strings separated by a '.' (dot):

- First four parts are always STG.FTG.ADG.Common
- Fifth part can be one or more words(Alphanumeric) separated by a '.', so it could be ABC, ABC.DEF.G, but it cannot be one of the three strings (IMAP|SMTP|POP3)
- Sixth part is one of the 3 following string (IMAP|SMTP|POP3)
- Seventh, and last, part is a single word(Alphanumeric)

I've come up with this:

```
^STG\.FTG\.ADG\.Common\.(?!>IMAP|SMTP|POP3)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*?(?:IMAP|SMTP|POP3)(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

And tested it with the following examples:

- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Testing.test.IMAP.word
- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Testing.test.IMAP
- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Testing.IMAP.word
- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Testing.IMAP.IMAP.word
- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Components.IMAP STG.FTG.ADG.Common.IMAP.test
- STG.FTG.ADG.Common.IMAP.Tasdfa1566asdflksjad STG.FTG.ADG.Common.IMAP

2nd, 4th, 5th and last example should not be validated, all aren't except the 4th (STG.FTG.ADG.Common.Testing.IMAP.IMAP.word), which is considered a match, but it can't be since it has IMAP, which belongs to the next element.

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: What's up with innovative title **Regular Expression for a**

Comment: @anubhava I forgot to edit the title, thank you

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: @JNYRanger C# flavour

Comment: Regarding your "fifth part": if I got it right "IMAP" is not a valid 5th part. But is "ABC.IMAP" a valid 5th part?

Comment: I suggest that you don't do this as a regex.  Split apart your string on the periods and then check each value on its own.

Comment: I would agree with @AndyLester that this doesn't look like Regex is the best tool for the job here.  Tokenize all the parts by splitting on the '.' and then validate each token individually using the current index of the token to switch around your validations.  For each token you could use regex, but not for the whole thing.

Comment: Plus, if something doesn't validate, you're going to want to explain to the user what doesn't validate, right?  You can't do that with a regex, which is just pass/fail.  When you break apart the components, then you can explain "4th section cannot be [whatever]" or "6th section must contain [whatever]".

Comment: @AndyLester Hello Andy, Indeed I ended up splitting by the '.', you're right, Regex isn't a good approach on this one! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JNYRanger Thanks for your help! I had to do it like that, splitting by the '.' and validating each part..